# Implementing Dependency Injection (DI) for CleanArchitecture Azure Function Project

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, azure-functions, clean-architecture

**Problem**:
I'm working on a project based on Jason Taylor's CleanArchitecture, and I need to implement Dependency Injection (DI) for my Azure Function project. Specifically, I want to inject the ApplicationDbContext and some other services from the infrastructure layer.

**Code**:
Below is the constructor implementation for ApplicationDbContext inside the Infrastructure layer:

```
public ApplicationDbContext(
    ICurrentUserService currentUserService,
    IDateTime dateTime,
    IGetLocalIPAddress getLocalIPAddress,
    DbContextOptions options,
    IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions,
    IAzureKeyVaultService azureKeyVaultService,
    IMediator mediator,
    IConfiguration config,
    AuditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor auditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor)
    : base(options)
{
    // Constructor implementation
}
```

I have already registered this service in my **Program.cs** file inside the **WEBUI **project:

builder.Services.AddInfrastructureServices(builder.Configuration);

And this is the **configuration **file inside the **Infrastructure **layer:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructureServices(this IServiceCollection services,         IConfiguration configuration)
{
// DbContext registration
// ...

services.AddScoped<AuditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor>();

// Other services registration
// ...
}
```

And in my AzureFunction project's Program.cs file, I've done the following:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        // I need help here to properly inject the required services, especially          ApplicationDbContext.
    // ...
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**Note**
I have already tried  this way

**Question**:
Could you please guide me on how to correctly implement Dependency Injection for the ApplicationDbContext and the other required services in my AzureFunction project based on CleanArchitecture? I'm facing some issues with the current setup. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I am trying to use the services inside my **Azurefuntion ** project From Cleanarchitech project.
facing issues while performing **DI**

**Issue**
[Snapshot of complete issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ynn1.png)

```cs
Description 

[2023-08-04T06:56:43.812Z] Worker process started and initialized.
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.152Z] Function 'Function1', Invocation id '35805df3-ec58-4754-9a83-a0ec65f6231f': An exception was thrown by the invocation.
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.154Z] Result: Function 'Function1', Invocation id '35805df3-ec58-4754-9a83-a0ec65f6231f': An exception was thrown by the invocation.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Emms3M.Application.Common.Interfaces.ICurrentUserService' while attempting to activate 'Emms3M.Infrastructure.Persistence.ApplicationDbContext'.
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.155Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.155Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.156Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.156Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.157Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.158Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.159Z]    at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.159Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.160Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.161Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.162Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ConfigureServices.<>c.<AddInfrastructureServices>b__0_2(IServiceProvider provider) in E:\LpInfotech\Workspace\Emms\src\Infrastructure\ConfigureServices.cs:line 32
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.162Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.163Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.164Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.164Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.166Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.166Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.167Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.167Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.168Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.169Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.DefaultFunctionActivator.CreateInstance(Type instanceType, FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionActivator.cs:line 23
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.169Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionInvoker`2.CreateInstance(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionInvoker.cs:line 26
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.171Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionExecutor.cs:line 30
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.172Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:line 13
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.172Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication.InvokeFunctionAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\FunctionsApplication.cs:line 77
Stack:    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.173Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.173Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.174Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.175Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.175Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.176Z]    at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.176Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.177Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.178Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.187Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ConfigureServices.<>c.<AddInfrastructureServices>b__0_2(IServiceProvider provider) in E:\LpInfotech\Workspace\Emms\src\Infrastructure\ConfigureServices.cs:line 32
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.188Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.188Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.189Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.190Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.190Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.191Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.191Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.192Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.193Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.194Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.DefaultFunctionActivator.CreateInstance(Type instanceType, FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionActivator.cs:line 23
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.194Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionInvoker`2.CreateInstance(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionInvoker.cs:line 26
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.196Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionExecutor.cs:line 30
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.197Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:line 13
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.198Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication.InvokeFunctionAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\FunctionsApplication.cs:line 77.
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.218Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Failed, Id=35805df3-ec58-4754-9a83-a0ec65f6231f, Duration=3795ms)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.219Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.Function1. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Emms3M.Application.Common.Interfaces.ICurrentUserService' while attempting to activate 'Emms3M.Infrastructure.Persistence.ApplicationDbContext'.
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.220Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.221Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.222Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.223Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.224Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.225Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.225Z]    at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.226Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.227Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.228Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.228Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ConfigureServices.<>c.<AddInfrastructureServices>b__0_2(IServiceProvider provider) in E:\LpInfotech\Workspace\Emms\src\Infrastructure\ConfigureServices.cs:line 32
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.229Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.229Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.230Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.230Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.231Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.232Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.232Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.233Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.233Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.234Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.DefaultFunctionActivator.CreateInstance(Type instanceType, FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionActivator.cs:line 23
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.234Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionInvoker`2.CreateInstance(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionInvoker.cs:line 26
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.235Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionExecutor.cs:line 30
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.235Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:line 13
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.236Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication.InvokeFunctionAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\FunctionsApplication.cs:line 77
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.237Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Handlers.InvocationHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationRequest request) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\Handlers\InvocationHandler.cs:line 88
Stack:    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.237Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.238Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.238Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.239Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.240Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.241Z]    at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.241Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.242Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.243Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.243Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ConfigureServices.<>c.<AddInfrastructureServices>b__0_2(IServiceProvider provider) in E:\LpInfotech\Workspace\Emms\src\Infrastructure\ConfigureServices.cs:line 32
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.244Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.245Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.245Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.246Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.246Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.247Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.248Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.248Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.249Z]    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.249Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.DefaultFunctionActivator.CreateInstance(Type instanceType, FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionActivator.cs:line 23
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.250Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionInvoker`2.CreateInstance(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionInvoker.cs:line 26
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.251Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionExecutor.cs:line 30
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.251Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:line 13
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.252Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication.InvokeFunctionAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\FunctionsApplication.cs:line 77
[2023-08-04T06:56:44.252Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Handlers.InvocationHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationRequest request) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\Handlers\InvocationHandler.cs:line 88.
```

I wanted to use azure **Time trigger ** function to get data from Sql server database and hit 3rd party api update the record from api to database

Comment: _"facing issues while performing DI"_ - I'm afraid to sound kind of obvious but what issues EXACTLY?

Comment: @GuruStron thanks for you reaching out, I have just added the complete description, please review it once,

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error the `ApplicationDbContext` is already registered, you need to provide dependencies for it, this particular error is about missing registration for `ICurrentUserService`, so you need to add one For example:

```cs
services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService, SomeCurrentUserServiceImpl>();
```

You will need to add other services in the same manner.

Comment: I have added this before registering ApplicationDBContext, still no luck.

Comment: @VIvek 1) has the exception changed? 2) Please provide full [mre] code.

Comment: Yes, it changed,



 Result: Function 'Function1', Invocation id '32169462-a231-474a-b57d-ca9c4eb6465f': An exception was thrown by the invocation.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' while attempting to activate 'Emms3M.WebUI.Services.CurrentUserService'.

Comment: @VIvek so the previous is fixed. You need to register all dependencies. This one requires `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` call for example.

Comment: You are correct, I had tried registering all the dependencies, but still I can't able to access ApplicationDBContext, let me share you with minimal reproducible example,